# Using R to scrape tables when URL does not change

Tags: r, phantomjs, rvest

I'm relatively new to scraping in R and have had great luck using "rvest", but I've run into an issue I cannot solve.

The website I am trying to scrape has the same URL no matter what page of the table you are on.  For example, the main webpage is www.blah.com with one main table on it that has 10 other "next" pages of the same table, but just the next in order (I apologize for not linking to the actual page as I cannot due to work issues).

So, if I'm on page 1 of the table, the URL is www.blah.com.  If I'm on page 2 of the table the URL is www.blah.com and so on...  The URL never changes.

Here is my code so far.  I'm using a combination of rvest and phantomjs.  The code works perfectly, but only for getting page 1 of the table, not the corresponding "next" 10 pages of the table:

```
url <- "http://www.blah.com"

writeLines(sprintf("var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('%s', function () {
   console.log(page.content); //page source
   phantom.exit();
});", url), con="scrape.js")

system(phantomjs scrape.js > scrape.html") 

page <- html("scrape.html")
page %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text()
```

And, this is the HTML code for page 2 of the table from the website (all other pages of the table are identical except for replacing the 2 with 3 and so on up the list):

```
<li><a href="#" id="p_2">2</a></li>
```

Thanks so much for any advice/help you can give!

Comment: Every webpage is different so it's nearly impossible to make a suggestion that will work for every site. But from your description it sounds like the data is being updated via javascript. Rather than running system calls, you'll probably want to look into running [RSelenium with phantomjs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html) so you can interactively work with a webpage and execute it's java script.

Comment: The "same page" behavior suggest it's using `xmlhttprequest`s. Try using your browser's network inspector (developer tools) and seeing what it calls out to each update. You can prbly discern the data retrieval URL and data structures and just make those same calls with `rvest`

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick for your help.  I looked all over the internet to find you an example of what I'm referring to here and this is the best website I could find:  http://www.athletic.net/CrossCountry/Division/List.aspx?DivID=26935&D=8000 -- notice how if you select a different page of the table, the URL stays the same.  This is very much like my problem.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr.  As I said, I'm fairly new to this, so I'm not quite sure how to see what the webpage calls out to each update.  I know how to view the inspector/developer tools, but I'm not sure how I would be able to see what changes it's making.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated if you have the time.  Also, here is a website that is similar to my situation: http://www.athletic.net/CrossCountry/Division/List.aspx?DivID=26935&D=8000 if you want to use that.

Comment: abet, regarding your last comment: this other website may have something that *looks* like your problem, but it *is not* your problem necessarily. as @MrFlick said, each website is different. I think your question isn't about r, but rather about html, javascripting and web-scraping, and there are appropriate tags for that. you'll have better chances there.

Comment: I should have tried a little more before responding.  I apologize, @hrbrmstr.  Here is what I have found -- I used the website I linked above to see if I could find any differences in the pages while in inspector/developer tools.  What I found was the "data-currentpage="1" was what seemed to be changing.  I'm unsure how to pull this out to use within rvest.  Any ideas?  `<div id="PageContent" data-division="26935" data-distance-id="8000" data-distance-id2="-1" data-grades="" data-currentpage="2">`

Comment: Hi djas.  You're absolutely right.  I've done a lot of searching through google, et al.   I was just hoping there might be somebody who had a very similar situation.  I'll keep searching and thank you for your help/time.

Comment: It looks like its using a POST with param `txtPage`

Comment: @hadley - thank you for this.  Do you know of any way to use your rvest program to pull out the data?  By the way, I love rvest!

Comment: You'll need to use `httr::POST()` to send the request, then you can use `rvest::html()` on the response

Comment: @hadley - Thank you.  I was almost there, but was missing small parts.  So, thank you for the advice...I very much appreciate your help.