# Web-scraping in R when a table changes but the URL does not

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape NCAA gymnastics scores from roadtonationals.com into R.  I have been able to do this in the past, using readLines(), but the website has been updated recently, and my old code no longer works.

In particular, when I am looking at the standings (roadtonationals.com/results/standings/), I can change season, year, week, and team/individual using the drop down menus.  I can change between the four events and the all around using the tabs on the right.  However, even if the table changes, the URL remains the same.  I know very little about coding for websites, so I don’t even really know what this type of table is called or where to start with it.

Technically, I could copy and paste, but eventually, I’d like each individual score, like I used to be able to get, from a page like roadtonationals.com/results/schedule/meet/20409, which also involves selecting the teams or the events without changing the URL.

I found this question:

[Using R to scrape tables when URL does not change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438010/using-r-to-scrape-tables-when-url-does-not-change)

which seems to be asking the same thing that I am.

However, when I tried

```
library(httr)

standings <- POST(url = "https://roadtonationals.com/results/standings/season")
```

I get a message that says, “Not Acceptable.” and “An appropriate representation of the requested resource /results/standings/season could not be found on this server.”

Comment: You should try `RSelenium`

Comment: It allows you perform those click/menu selection actions from R, then you can extract the data you need.

Comment: No, you should use browser developer tools, watch the XHR URLs as you click — they'll look like `https://www.roadtonationals.com/api/women/results/2014/2/1/5` — and make `httr::GET` calls with some `jsonlite::fromJSON` thrown in. Try to avoid heavy dependencies like Selenium or Splash at all cost.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Jul, as I didn't even know where to start, so I was glad to know it was possible.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you, I think this is exactly what I was looking for without knowing what it was I was looking for!

Comment: Was this question answered with sufficient detail and were you (the OP) able to scrape tables that do not change the URL on clicking anything? It will be nice if you posted your solution as as answer (answering your own question).