# How do I pull all the data found in a multi-page website table into Power BI?

Tags: html, url, web-scraping, powerbi

Using Power BI, I am attempting to extract all the data in a table found on [NBA Player Stats](https://stats.nba.com/players/traditional/?sort=PTS&dir=-1&Season=2019-20&SeasonType=Regular%20Season). I'm able to extract the data just fine, but the table only lists the 50 rows that are found on the first page of the table out of what should be a grand total 484 rows. In my very limited html knowledge, I have tried changing the page number to "All" and then seeing if that changes the URL, but the URL does not change. To summarize, I would like to extract all 484 rows of data rather than just the default 50 that appear when using the URL in Power BI.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question in the title but for that particular site you can use the raw JSON data that feeds the table on the site:

```
https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=
```

In Power BI use Get Data -> Other -> Web and then you'll need to transform the JSON from a series of Lists to a table.

[image: NBA Stats JSON Feed in PowerBI]

Comment: I might be able to make that work! What were the steps you took to make that table?

Comment: @JoshThibault  As a BI newb [this thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Multi-Dimensional-Json-file-to-Table/td-p/113667) was the most helpful to me. I used the first couple steps from the accepted solution and then the first post from `ImkeF` in that thread to save myself from having to manually make each column.

Comment: That's just what I need. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you take a look at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830897/am-i-using-the-correct-site-to-view-the-raw-json-data) I have?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no straight forward way to do this. From the looks of it, the webpage is using java scripting to get the information. This is a problem you would have run into irrespective of what platform you use. I am not sure if this can be done in Power BI, but I would suggest you use tools like RStudio to manipulate the data before ingesting it into Power BI. The following link is a similar discussion where the user is trying to extract information using r:

[Using R to scrape tables when URL does not change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438010/using-r-to-scrape-tables-when-url-does-not-change)

This should give you some further clarity. Hope this helps.

*Note: If its a one time thing, copying and pasting the information into an excel file would work as well*