# Am I using the correct site to view the raw JSON data?

Tags: json, google-chrome, url, web-scraping

Using [NBA Team Stats](https://stats.nba.com/teams/traditional/?sort=TEAM_NAME&dir=-1) through Google Chrome's network tool, I believe I located the site to lead me to the raw JSON data

[image: Preview]

As a result, I am using the following URL:

```
https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=
```

However, when I try to go to the above site, it does not load. This leads me to believe that perhaps I am looking at the wrong piece of information to get me to where I am trying to go. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, research, and trial & error, I was finally able to come up with a Python script (within Power BI) that would give me exactly what I needed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import requests
import json

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9','Connection': 'keep-alive','Host': 'stats.nba.com',
          'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/','Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors','Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
          Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36','x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats','x-nba-stats-token': 
          'true',}

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&
    Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&
    Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&
    PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2019-20&
    SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&
    VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight='

json = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

data = json['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']
columns = json['resultSets'][0]['headers']

PpgData = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=columns)
```

Using this script allows me to convert all the JSON data to a table that will be properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

That specific page seems to require a Referer header to be sent with the request so just loading it on it's own won't work.

In Power BI you can set custom headers if you select Advanced when adding a Web data source. In the optional Header section enter `Referer` and a value of `https://stats.nba.com/`.

Comment: Once again, you've saved the day! I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Would you use the same referer for `https://stats.nba.com/players/advanced/?sort=GP&dir=-1`? It doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @JoshThibault Looks like `x-nba-stats-origin:stats` works right now. Funny because it didn't require this a couple days ago on the original question.

Comment: I've tried including both `https://stats.nba.com/` as a `Referer` and `x-nba-stats-origin: stats`, but I haven't had any luck. I've tried them individually as well, and I get the same result.

Comment: Try adding the Cookie value from your browser as a header maybe.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886998/what-headers-am-i-missing-to-scrape-the-nba-stats-data) so you can take a look at it further if interested.

Comment: Are you still able to extract the JSON data? I'm not having any luck now.

Comment: No it feels like they changed something.

Comment: Do you think it's possible we've been detected as bots? Or is it something more in-depth?

Comment: It's possible. Might want to look into an intermediate script to fetch the json. I see there are some python scripts that use selenium to mimic a browser if you google `scrape nba stats`.

Comment: Are you able to pull if you use the **required headers** listed in **Sers** response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206604/discussion-between-cole2-and-josh-thibault).