# What headers am I missing to scrape the NBA Stats data?

Tags: html, json, web-scraping, powerbi, host

A couple of days ago in Power BI, I was able to create a web query that allowed me to extract the JSON data from [NBA Player Stats](https://stats.nba.com/players/traditional/?sort=PTS&dir=-1) without using any headers. As of today, I have noticed that the query no longer works; I am getting the following error message:

```
DataSource.Error: The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Details: https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=
```

On a related note, I used to be able to pull the JSON data from [NBA Team Stats](https://stats.nba.com/teams/traditional/?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1) using `https://stats.nba.com/` as a `Referer` header, but now it's giving me the same error message as shown above. To try and get around these errors, I have tried entering the following headers:

```
Host: stats.nba.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
x-nba-stats-token: true
User-Agent: Chrome/79.0.3945.130
x-nba-stats-origin: stats
Referer: https://stats.nba.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

When I do submit the query with the above headers, it comes back with the following error message:

```
Unable to connect

We encountered an error while trying to connect.

Details: "The 'Host' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name"
```

I have run out of ideas as to how I'm able to properly run the query. I'm really new to web-scraping and HTML -- I've been trying to teach myself. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add error messages as text, not screenshots.

Comment: Note that you may be violating the terms of service of the website. You tread on shaky legal ground here...

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

All headers for GET request:

```
Host: stats.nba.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
x-nba-stats-token: true
X-NewRelic-ID: VQECWF5UChAHUlNTBwgBVw==
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
x-nba-stats-origin: stats
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: https://stats.nba.com/teams/traditional/?sort=TEAM_NAME&dir=-1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.7
```

URL:

```
https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=
```

Required Headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
x-nba-stats-origin: stats
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: https://stats.nba.com/teams/traditional/?sort=TEAM_NAME&dir=-1
```

Not sure if required:

```
x-nba-stats-token: true
X-NewRelic-ID: VQECWF5UChAHUlNTBwgBVw==
```

**Possible problems**:

1. You detected as a bot and blocked
2. Header `X-NewRelic-ID` is a token (maybe with timeout). Probably it's assign using different params like `IP`, User-Agent and among others. 
   You can get fresh `X-NewRelic-ID` in HTML response with GET request to `https://stats.nba.com/`.
   Here is a part from HTML with `xpid` token:
   `<script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpid:"VQECWF5UChAHUlNTBwgBVw==",licenseKey:"09f0cb5c68",applicationID:"76210961"};`

Comment: After entering all those headers, it gives me the same "Unable to connect" error message as I have in my question with regards to the 'Host' header.

Comment: Check the answer update. I think you detected as a bot and blocked. Try from different IP. You can use proxy for that.

Comment: Are you able to extract the JSON data on your end? I'm curious to see if you are able to so I can determine if it would be something on my end -- like if I'm being detected as a bot.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to extract

Comment: Did you use all of the required headers? I've tried doing the required, as well as `x-nba-stats-token: true` and `X-NewRelic-ID: VQECWF5UChAHUlNTBwgBVw==`, but it's still not able to pull.

Comment: I was able to get data with **required headers** I specified, without `x-nba-stats-token: true` and `X-NewRelic-ID: VQECWF5UChAHUlNTBwgBVw==`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206611/discussion-between-josh-thibault-and-sers).

Comment: I was finally able to create a Python script that provided me with what I needed. Here's the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830897/am-i-using-the-correct-site-to-view-the-raw-json-data/59955532#59955532).